# Count values by key in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I look for something that will count values in dict (automatically)without use a list of element

```
d = {}

d["x1"] = "1"
{'x1':'1'}

d["x1"] = "2"
{'x1':'2'}

d["x1"] = "3"
{'x1':'3'}

d["x2"] = "1"
{'x1':'3', 'x2':'1'}
```

ect..

I try create a list them using

```
for x in list:
    d[x] = list.count(x)
```

But when I created a list , I receive a memory error

Comment: You can only have 1 key per value in a dict, so everything will be 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you want to use a `dict` to do it? It seems a [Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) or a [defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) suits your need more.

```
>>> d = collections.Counter()
>>> d['x1'] += 1
>>> d
Counter({'x1': 1})
>>> d['x1'] += 1
>>> d
Counter({'x1': 2})
>>> d['x2'] += 1
>>> d
Counter({'x1': 2, 'x2': 1})
```

You could also convert a sequence to a counter:

```
>>> collections.Counter(['x1', 'x1', 'x2'])
Counter({'x1': 2, 'x2': 1})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
>>> d = defaultdict(int)
>>> d['foo'] += 1
>>> d['foo'] += 1
>>> d['bar'] += 1
>>> for i in d:
...   print i,d[i]
... 
foo 2
bar 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dict` in the following manner -

```
d['x1'] = d.get('x1', 0) + 1
```

The second argument in `get` specifies the object to return if the key supplied in the first argument is not found.

Applying this on your example:

```
from pprint import pprint
d = {}
d['x1'] = d.get('x1', 0) + 1
d['x1'] = d.get('x1', 0) + 1
d['x1'] = d.get('x1', 0) + 1
d['x2'] = d.get('x2', 0) + 1
pprint(d)    # will print {'x1': 3, 'x2': 1}
```